# HTML5 Canvas wont show clicks correctly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, click

Basically, I have a code which shows where the user clicks on the canvas:

```
canvas.onclick = function(e){
    ctx.fillRect(e.clientX,e.clientY,10,10);
}
```

It works perfectly well if I include this in the code:

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
```

But I want the width and height of the canvas to be 200! Like this:

```
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;
```

Whenever I try this, the clicks go all wrong! How can I have a width of 200 on my fullscreen canvas without resizing it or the window???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that all you are missing is to substract the canvas offsets...

Here is a code example

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('can');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 2, 2);

canvas.onclick = function(e) {
  r = 10
  x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft - r
  y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop - r
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, r, r);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I tried that...I dont think thats it, but thanks.

Comment: No.........What I need is a way to accurately show clicks on a canvas with a absolute size(pixels). The canvas should always take up the whole screen : width:100%;

Comment: 200px. But I need the canvas to take up the whole screen. (Fullscreen)